# is Snow Leopard Server ready for production?

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I installed my 2 XServe 1 week after SL was out, I refrained to start with 10.6.0. I'm planning to upgrade both to 10.6.2 or perhaps I should wait for 10.6.3? Do you consider SLS ready for a production environment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I have it on a few servers and it seems as reliable as 10.5.8 did. We're running 10.6.2 on all of them (XServes and a Mac mini 'server'.

If you are going to do an upgrade or migration for 10.5.8 make sure your server is working great (I had to migrate a dented 10.5.x server to 10.6.2 and it brought some messed up OpenDirectory entries for some old sharepoints). Otherwise you might bring along any problems you had from before. I would to a Carbon Copy Clone before upgrading just to be safe :)

Comment: Yes that's the plan - fresh install and importing server admin settings where needed. Or even better, to minimize downtime, install on a firewire disk SLS, patch it all and do a minimal configuration, then clone it back into the internal RAID. The upgrade is specifically to solve OD issues (can't replicate anymore).

Comment: Are you going to export your users & groups and reset all the passwords or are you going to try to do an OD backup/restore?

Answer (score 0):

We've used it in production since October, and have had very few problems with it on our Xserves.  If anything, it is the client that has been a bit problematic.

To solve your OD problems, you might want to just burn it down and start over.  Migrating an OD directory piece-by-piece is incredibly difficult.  However, if you want to attempt it, create a backup of OD using Server Admin.  It will produce a disk image full of interesting things which you can inspect, edit, and then re-import as necessary.  For example, you might want to look through the exported LDIF file, and then re-import parts of it back into your fresh OD.  Good luck!